# Linking Bing Search API Key to Bing Custom Search Key

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have an azure account and Bing Search Api Key. I can query to this url with my key:

> curl --header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: MY_BING_SEARCH_API_KEY" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/**bing**/v5.0/search?q=microsoft&mkt=en-us"

After I login to www.customsearch.ai and create some custom search instance. This endpoint gives me a new api key with rate limits. I want to use my Bing Search Api Key in Bing Custom Search Key. Failed request is like this:

> curl --header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: MY_BING_SEARCH_API_KEY"
>   "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/**bingcustomsearch**/v5.0/search?q=microsoft&**customconfig=11111111**&mkt=en-us"

It returns:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```